# Find near query MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I need to "translate",in java, **this shell query** (MongoDB):

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: 'test', near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [115.0. 12.0]}, spherical: true, maxDistance: 40000})
```

I use mongo-java-driver:3.1.0, i test this query with shell and works fine.

Document:

{id: "test", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [115.2, 12.2]}}

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want the list of all documents near a specific coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write and BasicDBObject that construct the query:

BasicDBObject queryOnlyFind = new BasicDBObject("geometry",
                new BasicDBObject ("$near", 
                        new BasicDBObject("type","Point").append("coordinates",new double[] {0,0})
                        )
                );

Then:
    Collection.find(queryOnlyFind) and the result is the list of all documents.